# How Can I round the values thick plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have this small script for produce a plot:

```
plt.plot(loss_test3)
plt.plot(loss)
plt.legend(['loss_test3','loss_test4'], loc='upper left')
t = np.linspace(loss.min(), loss_test3.max(), 5)
plt.yticks(t, t)
plt.xlim(0, 200)
plt.title('test 4 loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.savefig('test_4_loss.png', dpi=100)
plt.show()
```

The output that I get is this:

[image]

How can i round the values on the Y axis?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in this way:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import StrMethodFormatter

    plt.plot(loss_test3)
    plt.plot(loss)
    plt.legend(['loss_test3','loss_test4'], loc='upper left')
    #t = [loss.min(), loss.max()]
    t = np.linspace(loss.min(), loss_test3.max(), 5)
    plt.yticks(t, t)
    plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.3f}'))
    plt.xlim(0, 200)
    plt.title('test 4 loss')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.savefig('test_4_loss.png', dpi=100)
    plt.show()
```